# Android Studio with intent to other activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
intent.putExtra ( "result", (double) kg / (Math.pow (tall, 2)) / 10000);// <SecondActivity> 
     result = intent.getDoubleExtra double ("result", 0); //<ThirdActivity>
     I have tried the following: 

     tall: 150 cm 
     kg: 50kg 
     result: 1.95 .... (original calculations. 19.5) 

    Even if the value does not appear 10 Multiply.
```

### ★ float cast upon the results will not come.

The problem occurs after fertilization in the post.
[Android Studio with intent to other activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807344/android-studio-with-intent-to-other-activities) 
(original code)

**[SecondActivity]**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

RadioGroup rg;
ImageButton button4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RadioButton rd = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            //String str_Qtype = rd.getText().toString();

            EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02); // tall (inot typing error)
            EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01); // kg (not typing error)

            int tall = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
            int kg = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("tall", Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()));
            intent.putExtra("kg", Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString()));
            intent.putExtra("result",(double)kg/(Math.pow(tall,2))/10000);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**[ThridActivity]**

```
package com.example.bmi_calculate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        int tall = intent.getIntExtra("tall", 0);
        int kg = intent.getIntExtra("kg", 0);
        double result = intent.getDoubleExtra("result",0);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv1.setText("" + tall);
        tv2.setText("" + kg);
        tv3.setText(""+String.valueOf(result));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post SecondActivity's code, we can't assume you've passed the intent properly.

Comment: Do you have an xml file attached to that activity?

Answer (score 0):

To save the value, do this:

```
intent.putExtra("result",(float) (kg/((tall*0.01)*(tall*0.01))) ); // tall in cm unit
```

You need to get `float` value or save as `int`:

```
float result = intent.getFloatExtra("result", 0f);
```

[Edit] - fixed code typo

Comment: Not declare a float, an error occurs. But the cast appear strange to double this value.

Comment: Official adjusted to kg / (tall * 0.01) * (tall * 0.01).

Comment: Even intend to result in the Third Activity Second Activity This value is not passed properly.

Comment: SecondActvity in result -> intent -> ThirdActivity -> Erratic results

Comment: Explicitly cast to float while saving `intent.putExtra("result",(float) (kg/(tall*0.1)*(tall*0.1)));`...This should pass the value properly and read as above mentioned...If not let me know the exact error.

Comment: Result (result) will come with the same kg (weight) with a point value.

Comment: Ok...so are you taking the height in `cm` unit? If yes, the formula should be `kg / (tall * 0.01) * (tall * 0.01)`.

Comment: Intellectual submitted four parts will fit.
However, this phenomenon results in a value of 0.0 to discard me again occur.

Comment: @MinjuPark check my edited answer above. Works for me.

Comment: But the result does not come out.

For example, tall: If the loaded value of 50,: 150 / kg
The results will appear in 5000.

Comment: @MinjuPark But, the answer is coming correct in my test (I checked it with online BMI calculator too). For eg. a weight of 23 Kg and a height of 150 cm should give the bmi as 10.22, which I'm getting. Make sure your get the brackets correct as per my updated answer above.

Comment: <SecondActivity>
intent.putExtra ( "result", (double) kg / (Math.pow (tall, 2)) / 10000);

<ThirdActivity>
result = intent.getDoubleExtra double ("result", 0);

I have tried the following:
tall: 150 cm
kg: 50kg
result: 1.95 .... (original calculations. 19.5)

Even if the value does not appear 10 Multiply.

Comment: Please check Since we made changes to the source content.

Comment: Try this: `intent.putExtra ( "result", (double) (kg /( (Math.pow (tall, 2)) / 10000)) );`.

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity you are storing your results in variables tall and kg create a third variable result and pass that variable to the method

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RadioButton rd = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            //String str_Qtype = rd.getText().toString();

            EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02); // tall (inot typing error)
            EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01); // kg (not typing error)

            int tall = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
            int kg = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
            float result = kg/(tall*0.1)*(tall*0.1))
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("tall", tall);
            intent.putExtra("kg", kg);
            intent.putExtra("result",result);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and in third activity

```
float result = intent.getFloatExtra("result",0);
```

Comment: Not declare a float, an error occurs.
But the cast appear strange to double this value.

Comment: Official adjusted to kg / (tall * 0.01) * (tall * 0.01).